# Code Folding in RubyMine (MacOS)?

Tags: rubymine

Can't understand. How to trigger this keyboard shortcut for "Expand all to level 1,2,3,4"?

[image]

Comment: The icon after Alt Command means: numpad. Is that an answer to your question?

Comment: Yes, but there is no numpad on macbook.

Comment: In that case you only access this in the menu....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha! I found an answer.
Go to RubyMine -> preferences -> Keymap
In the big screen with all the menu items, you can select the menu item you need (in case of folding : Main Menu - Code - Folding).
Rightclick on the item you want, and there you can make your own keyboard shortcut, with keys which are actually on your keyboard ;-) Or even your own mouse click.